# command substitution breaks command substitution

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I extracted part of a shell script into another shell script, and for some reason after calling the sub-script, command substitution stops working.  I can't imagine it's something in the sub-script, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong, either.

whether i do:

```
dirname "$0"                                      # works
echo "`dirname "$0"`"                             # works
echo "$(dirname "$0")"                            # works
cat <<< "`dirname "$0"`"                          # works
cat <<< "$(dirname "$0")"                         # works
"$(dirname "$0")"/setup_buildroot.sh "$BUILDROOT" # call the sub-script
dirname "$0"                                      # works
echo "`dirname "$0"`"                             # empty string
echo "$(dirname "$0")"                            # empty string
cat <<< "`dirname "$0"`"                          # crash
cat <<< "$(dirname "$0")"                         # crash
```

or i do:

```
dirname "$0"                                      # works
echo "`dirname "$0"`"                             # works
echo "$(dirname "$0")"                            # works
cat <<< "`dirname "$0"`"                          # works
cat <<< "$(dirname "$0")"                         # works
"`dirname "$0"`"/setup_buildroot.sh "$BUILDROOT"  # call the sub-script
dirname "$0"                                      # works
echo "`dirname "$0"`"                             # empty string
echo "$(dirname "$0")"                            # empty string
cat <<< "`dirname "$0"`"                          # crash
cat <<< "$(dirname "$0")"                         # crash
```

dirname seems to work fine, but backtick and `$()` stop working.  The command substitution just returns an empty string.

EDIT: removing all the double quotes `""` doesn't have an effect

EDIT2: executing bash explicitly when calling the sub-script has no effect

EDIT3: saving `"$(dirname "$0")"` to a variable and using that has no effect

EDIT4: adding the same `echo` commands to the sub-script show that everything is fine in the sub-script

EDIT5: as per request, output of script

```
/home/jayen/rep
/home/jayen/rep
/home/jayen/rep
/home/jayen/rep
/home/jayen/rep
#setup_buildroot.sh output here
/home/jayen/rep


bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Comment: Does it work normally, if you just comment out line to call the subscript? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Can you give some details about the subscript?

Comment: Also, try to move your script/s to a directory not containing special characters, like space. Are you sure, that the subscript is ending & returning the control back to parent script?

Comment: Please show the actual output of the code.

Comment: yes, it works normally, if I just comment out the line that calls sub-script.  It also works if I didn't have the subscript and the 2 or 3 lines in there were inline.

Comment: The scripts are not in a directory with special characters.  All the protection is there for others who may use wonky directory names.

Comment: How can a sub-script end and affect the parent script?  It exits with status 0 (run directly or from the script).  There is no ill effect to an interactive shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't make sense, but try sourcing your sub-script

```
. "$(dirname "$0")"/setup_buildroot.sh "$BUILDROOT" # call the sub-script
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like calling the sub-script is breaking the environment variables of your existing bash script's session. Maybe try prefixing the sub-script line with `bash`, so

```
bash "`dirname "$0"`"/setup_buildroot.sh "$BUILDROOT"
```

and see if that fixes the issue. This is an odd situation.

The other solution I recommend is on the first line, do

```
mydir="$0"
```

and replace all the `$0` with `$mydir`

and better yet, do

```
mydir=`dirname "$0"`
```

up front and *not* rerun the command over and over.

Comment: tried both.  neither has an effect! `bash "$HERE"/setup_buildroot.sh $BUILDROOT`

Comment: replacing all of the `$0`'s in your script with `$HERE` (where `HERE=\`dirname "$0"\``) didn't work?

Comment: i just replaced this one.  it's the first one in the script.

Comment: I meant, not just the line dealing with the subscript. You have lots of echos and cats, and those should be changed as well. If your script repeats everything a few times, those don't matter as much unless the first run through works.

Comment: the rest of the script was working fine until i extracted out a few lines to a sub-script

Comment: I had a similar (not the same) problem, where a script that I've run many times in the past stopped working. Some underlying upgrade had caused the executing shell to be sh. I'm not sure why that disturbed command substitution, but forcing bash solved the problem and the script ran.